# websites with perl and sqlite

Tags: perl, sqlite

could you recommend any book to understand building websites with perl and sqlite. i have built websites in php and mysql and now need to look into another site code with perl and sqlite in it . any resources will be of help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=perl+books

Comment: I would recommend going with Perl and MySQL unless you expect the site to be strictly single-user-at-a-time. As much as I like SQLite, it has significant issues with concurrent updates, due it it being an in-process db engine rather than having a separate server process to coordinate access.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward getting started page:

http://quickies.andreaolivato.net/post/123847804/perl-and-sqlite3-quick-start-example-guide